# is it possible to save data after commit statement in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

If 10 users are working on one table at once (e.g.-A1,A2,A3....,A10). Every one is performing DML operation on same table  parallel (i.e. insert,update and delete). If user A1 commit the transaction when others are performing operations. is possible to save all's transaction operations.(Yes/No)
If Yes then why?
If No the Why?

Answer (score 3):

No. Transactions are isolated as per [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

If a user A1 creates a transaction, then only he can commit it. This will make either all or none of his changes visible to other users. Depending on the isolation level of the transactions, other users will see committed changes by other users only after their own active transaction is committed (see [phantom/dirty/non-repeatable reads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29)).

Imagine this:

I'm in the middle of changing something in the database. For example, I'm deleting an object which user A1 has changed. If his commit commits my transaction, too, what should happen? Should he get an error because the object has/will vanish? Or should I get an error because the object was modified by another user?

There is no simple way to resolve these conflicts.

Cloud databases solve it by keeping a history of all objects. So when user A1 changes an object and I delete it, the DB will record the two changes but keep the object around. I can move in time to see A1's change and I can also see my "deletion".

Another point: You could write a server which synchronizes the changes made by all users. So there would always be only a single transaction open. If two users change the same objects, how do you resolve the conflicts?

Or you could write a server which keeps track of all transactions and commits them all at one, how do you make sure that half-valid objects are written to the database (like orders without items, invoices without totals, customers without addresses)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the question.

Are all the users operating on the same row of the table?  Or are they operating on different rows?  If they are operating on the same row, the sessions will necessarily lock each other-- only one session can update a row-- the other sessions would need to wait for the lock to be released when the transaction committed.  If they are operating on different rows, then User A's transaction will have no impact on User B-- it's not obvious to me what "transaction operations" you would want to save in that case or where you would want to save that information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you want is a history of the changes? In which case you can use either your own triggers to capture the changes or [Total Recall](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/options/total-recall/index.html) in Oracle 11g.